# In the beginning of San Andreas during the rescue of Natalie, why did they fly the helicopter into the crevice?

Tags: san-andreas

In *San Andreas*, the rescuers decided to fly the helicopter into a narrow aperture and almost clipped one of the blades on a wall. Why didn't they park the helicopter above the crevice and send someone down with a rope?

Comment: I enjoyed this movie a lot, but I suspect that they did it because it looked cooler on screen. I don't have any evidence to back that up, except for the wonderful ridiculousness of the rest of the movie. :)